# SSH project on github giving issues

Tags: git, ssh

I ran through the whole process of adding a key to Github and doing everything on this [guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) that Github provided, but afterwards, it asked every 5 min for the ssh passkey, which is quite annoying while working on a project, so a found a command that eases that but this morning I got an error saying the following

`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: C:WindowsSystem32OpenSSHssh.exe: command not found`

reran this to check if everything was fine

`$ ssh -T git@github.com`

it authenticated, but the error did not disappear, so I ran the same command that I got on Friday `git config --global --add core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`

Now when I do a 'refresh' (push and pull) to get the latest changes to my repo, it just keeps on synchronizing changes as if it is infinite looping and then timing out.

Edit***

If I run git pull in git bash I get the following output

```
$ git pull
CreateProcessW failed error:193
ssh_askpass: posix_spawnp: Unknown error
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

but before that, I ran `ssh -T git@github.com`

and I got the following output after entering the password

```
Hi Faziki! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to *not* use anything from Windows itself, but only from your [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (make sure to get the latest 2.33.0.2)

So remove any ssh setting from your global Git configuration, and make sure your `%PATH%` includes:

```sh
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

A `where ssh` in a CMD should give you: `C:\path\to\git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.

From there, from that same CMD, you can type "bash" to switch to a bash shelll session.
Make sure [your `~/.bashrc` automatically launch the ssh agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows).
And [add your private key to the agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent): that will cache the passkey.